# will google cloud functions 'always' be available via http?

Tags: google-cloud-functions

Maybe a strange question, but how long will google support http on cloud functions. Be default the https version of a cloud function will be used ofcourse.

But some IoT devices aren't able to create a secure connection and can only send (already encrypted) data straight to an IP addresses or http urls.

A static IP address pointing to a cloud function is not supported, but I do can send GET requests to the http version of a cloud function endpoint.

The only big thing is: If Google will ever redirect http to https, data will not come in anymore.

Regards, Peter

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems to be asking about the future of Cloud Functions.  There is no public roadmap for the development of Cloud Functions, so it's not really possible to say with certainty whether or not HTTP support will ever go away.  I suggest contacting Google Cloud support directly if you need a more definitive answer.